# computational number theoretic questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are computational number theoretic question in scope of math.stackexchange.com?
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118394/11206) the OP asks for a arithmetic progression of 6 primes 
and a commenter asked for an arithmetic progression of 10 primes starting with 101.
Is it on topic  to ask for an algorithm/program that calculates such a sequence of 10 numbers?
I already have  written such a program but I am interested in other and better approaches.

Comment: At the risk of oversimplifying, I'd say, mathematical questions are in scope, coding questions aren't.

Comment: I'd agree with @GerryMyerson. Asking for/about an algorithm is on topic, code rather not. But of course if you ask about other approaches, including your code if it is not too long is fine. (A several kloc dump is far too long.) Similar for answers, including code is okay, but a code-only answer is rarely if ever appropriate.

Comment: I agree that questions about algorithms to solve mathematical problems are certainly on topic, and I think the question linked to is definitely on topic.

Comment: [Related discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13626/do-questions-about-graph-theory-belong-here/22244)